# Running remote app in a shared host subdirectory domain

Tags: apache

I've built an app that's running in a VPS with a custom domain: myapp.mainsite.com.

http://mainsite.com lives in a shared host environment. Now my client wants to use a subdirectory as the app's main url, something like: http://mainsite.com/myapp.

So when someone types http://myapp.mainsite.com, the user would be redirected to http://mainsite.com/myapp url.

The shared host and the vps instance are using apache2 as the app server.

The problem is that I don't know how I could do the above thing. I read about apache's proxy_pass but didn't really understand how to do it.

Edit: Just to clarify things, the url that the user have to see where navigating is http://mainsite.com/myapp.

This is the apache configuration from the vps instance:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8080>
    ServerName {{ VPS IP }}
    ServerAlias {{ VPS IP }}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi

    # pass authorization info on (needed for rest api)
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    # Deploy as a daemon (avoids conflicts between CKAN instances)
    WSGIDaemonProcess ckan_default display-name=ckan_default processes=2 threads=15

    WSGIProcessGroup ckan_default

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.custom.log combined

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the nginx one:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=250m;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx_proxy 1 2;

server {
    server_name myapp.mainsite.com;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_cache_valid 30m;
        proxy_cache_key $host$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
        # In emergency comment out line to force caching
        # proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }

}
```

Comment: When someone goes to http://myapp.mainsite.com, should he/she see http://myapp.mainsite.com or http://mainsite.com/myapp in the url bar ? Could you also add your apache configuration ?

Comment: Hey David, I'll add that info to the post.

Comment: Doesn't matter since you have only the one ``VirtualHost``, but ``ServerName`` and ``ServerAlias`` are supposed to be host names, not IP addresses. You also wouldn't use ``0.0.0.0`` in ``VirtualHost`` usually, but use ``*`` to indicate all interfaces. It still works how you have it because if Apache can't match ``VirtualHost`` properly it falls back to using the first one it found anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you currently have a VPS serving your app:

```
                    +----------------------------------+
myapp.mainsite.com  | +----------+     +-------------+ |
+---------------------> nginx:80 +-----> apache:8080 | |
                    | +----------+     +-------------+ |
                    |              VPS                 |
                    +----------------------------------+
```

You want to:

- redirect users to mainsite.com/myapp
- serve on `/myapp` your app

Like that:

```
                    +----------------------------------+
      mainsite.com  | +---------------+  / as usual    |
+---------------------> apache:80 (?) | +---------> …  |
                    | +---------------+                |         +---------+
                    |                    /myapp        |         |         |
                    |                   +----------------------> |  VPS    |
                    |          shared host             |         |         |
                    +----------------------------------+         +---------+
```

### step 1, redirect users

On your VPS, in nginx:

```
server {
    server_name myapp.mainsite.com;

    location / {
        return 301 http://mainsite.com/myapp/;
    }

    location /myapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/;
        # …
    }
}
```

See below for an explanation of the `location /myapp/`.

### step 2, proxy requests from the shared host to the VPS

On the shared host, in the apache configuration, add:

```
<Location /myapp/>
    ProxyPass http://myapp.mainsite.com/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse http://myapp.mainsite.com/myapp/
</Location>
```

### step 3, (try to) update your app for `/myapp/`

When you proxy requests, it will be way easier to keep the same path: proxying `/` to `/` or `/myapp/` to `/myapp` for example. If you proxy `/a` to `/b/c`, the proxy itself will need to rewrite the response: `<img src="/a/test.png">` needs to be changed to `<img src="/b/c/test.png">`. Or [worse](https://serverfault.com/a/561897/367929), `<img src="../c/test.png" />`. Add relative references in html, js and css too. This is doable but it can use regex and it is error prone ([mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) will help you in apache 2.4).

If you can make you application work on `/myapp/`, you're (almost) done (I didn't test this solution so it may not magically work on the first time).

If not, remove a `/myapp/` in a proxy declaration and good luck !

---

An other gotcha: this solution (should) work because the `ProxyPass` directive uses `myapp.mainsite.com` which will match the nginx vhost on the VPS. If your application uses the host (to generate urls, redirects, etc), this won't work (because you will send `myapp.mainsite.com` to the user instead of `mainsite.com`). In that case, use [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) in the apache (shared host) proxy and create an other vhost in nginx (vps) to handle `mainsite.com`.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm trying this: are you sure about the urls in step 2?

Comment: In step 2, `myapp.mainsite.com` means requests will be sent from apache (shared host) to nginx (vps) with the HTTP header `Host: myapp.mainsite.com`, even if the user sees `http://mainsite.com` in the browser. With this host the request goes to the correct vhost in nginx. Using the ip address of nginx means the request would go the to default vhost (if you only have one vhost on this server, you will have more options). About `/myapp/`, see step 3.

Comment: Using ``ProxyPass`` in Apache configuration is overkill. You would use rewrite rules using ``mod_rewrite`` and do a redirect and avoid needing to do another request back against the server.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but I'm returning to this issue. The problem with the ProxyPass directive is that I can't include it in the .htaccess file which is the only apache file I have access to in the webfaction shared host.